# Passing value between functions in C++

Tags: c++

I'm making a program for car company which has only 6 Salesman. The program will ask the user to input the name of each salesmen and his monthly salary, input the number of cars he sold in a month, as well as the brand and price of each car. The program will display the  monthly income of each salesman (salary  +  commission), the average monthly income of the salesmen, the name(and income) of the salesman who has the highest income, the name (and income)of the salesman with the lowest income, the number of cars sold for each brand and the most popular 
brand.

I'm stuck at passing the value of totalCommission from Salesman1() and Salesman2(). Another problem is, i don't know if i can CIN a string into an array named SalesmanName. Here is what i have done so far.

```
int main()
{       
int cycle=1;
int SalesMan1(),SalesMan2();


do
{
    switch(cycle)
    {
        case 1: SalesMan1(); cycle++; break;
        case 2: SalesMan2(); cycle++; break;
        /*case 3: SalesMan3(); cycle++; break;
        case 4: SalesMan4(); cycle++; break;
        case 5: SalesMan5(); cycle++; break;
        case 6: SalesMan6(); cycle++; break;*/
        default: cout<<"Printing out reports"<<endl;
                 system("\npause");
    }
}while(cycle<=6);  

return 0;                                                                                              

}

int SalesMan1()
{
  char NameOne[40];
  int numCar=1,carSold,carType,audiSold=0,bmwSold=0,mbenzSold=0;
  double salary,carPrize,commission,totalCommission,allMonthlyIncome;

  cout<<"Name of 1st Salesman:"<<endl;
  cin.getline(NameOne,39);

  cout<<"\nMonthly Salary: RM";
  cin>>salary;

  cout<<"\nNumber of car sold in a month: ";
  cin>>carSold;
  system("CLS");

  do{
      cout<<"\nEnter type of car sold as below: "<<endl;
      cout<<"\n1-Audi"<<endl;
      cout<<"2-BMW"<<endl;
      cout<<"3-Mercedes Benz"<<endl;
      cout<<"\nCar Type:";
      cin>>carType;

      switch(carType)
      {
        case 1:
            cout<<"\nEnter the price sold: RM";
            cin>>carPrize;
            commission=0.02*carPrize;
            totalCommission+=commission;
            audiSold++;
            system("CLS");
            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"\nEnter the price sold: RM";
            cin>>carPrize;
            commission=0.02*carPrize;
            totalCommission+=commission;
            bmwSold++;
            system("CLS");
            break;

        case 3:
            cout<<"\nEnter the price sold: RM";
            cin>>carPrize;
            commission=0.035*carPrize;
            totalCommission+=commission;
            mbenzSold++;
            system("CLS");
            break;

        default :
            cout<<"\nNot available!"<<endl;
            system("pause");
            return 1;
      }
      numCar++;
  }while(numCar<=carSold);

  allMonthlyIncome=allMonthlyIncome+totalCommission+salary;

}

int SalesMan2()
{
  char NameTwo[40];
  int numCar=1,carSold,carType,audiSold=0,bmwSold=0,mbenzSold=0;
  double salary,carPrize,commission,totalCommission,allMonthlyIncome;

  cout<<"Name of 2nd Salesman"<<endl;
  cin.getline(NameTwo,39);

  cout<<"\nMonthly salary: RM";
  cin>>salary;

  cout<<"\nNumber of car sold in a month: ";
  cin>>carSold;
  system("CLS");

  do{
      cout<<"\nEnter type of car sold as below: "<<endl;
      cout<<"\n1-Audi"<<endl;
      cout<<"2-BMW"<<endl;
      cout<<"3-Mercedes Benz"<<endl;
      cout<<"\nCar Type:";
      cin>>carType;

      switch(carType)
      {
        case 1:
            cout<<"\nEnter the price sold: RM";
            cin>>carPrize;
            commission=0.02*carPrize;
            totalCommission+=commission;
            audiSold++;
            system("CLS");
            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"\nEnter the price sold: RM";
            cin>>carPrize;
            commission=0.02*carPrize;
            totalCommission+=commission;
            bmwSold++;
            system("CLS");
            break;

        case 3:
            cout<<"\nEnter the price sold: RM";
            cin>>carPrize;
            commission=0.035*carPrize;
            totalCommission+=commission;
            mbenzSold++;
            system("CLS");
            break;

        default :
            cout<<"\nNot available!"<<endl;
            system("pause");
            return 1;
     }
     numCar++;
  }while(numCar<=carSold);

   allMonthlyIncome=allMonthlyIncome+totalCommission+salary;
}
```

Comment: if this is not really a homwork, why do not you use Java or C#?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). And take advantage of C++ features! You can read a C++ `std::string` with `>>` or with [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/). Take time to read [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/)

Comment: @KickButtowski , i don't know Java or C#. I only know C++. And i'm new to it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch done compiling. No error at all. But i'm confuse in using array.

Comment: What do you mean by "parsing values"? Parsing is something that a compiler does, when translating input into its internal language. Do you mean "Passing values"?

Comment: @ScriptKiddies if I were you, I would try to use Java or C# because  C++ is not right for this kind of application. I am sure if you can do code in C++, Java is easy as eating a pie. if you try to sell it, it would be better representation :)

Comment: @KickButtowski: It looks like homework!

Comment: @ScriptKiddies: No compiler error does not mean that your program makes sense or is not buggy! Did you read a book about [Programming in C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) ?

Comment: @Barmar My bad, already fixed it.

Comment: So what is it you're trying to do? If you want to pass values, you should pass them as arguments and return them as values. E.g. `return totalCommission;`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, it is a homework. I used to make a win form project. But not console type.

Comment: Then learn more C++ before starting to code. Your present code is crappy (e.g. the number of salesmen should not matter much and should be a constant; you should use C++ types like `std::string`-s and C++ STL containers like `std::vector` or `std::list` or `std::map`) Burn it and start from scratch after having read some good C++ material. And use the debugger (and compile with all warnings)!

Comment: @Barmar Yes! Can i get the value of totalCommission from the Salesman() function? If yes, how?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Alright. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 2):

In the `SalesmanN()` functions, end it with:

```
return totalCommission;
```

In `main()`, do:

```
int allCommissions = 0;
```

and then in your loop you do:

```
case 1: allCommissions += SalesMan1(); cycle++; break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can CIN into any character array but it is not preferred for names as CIN limits its input on spaces. The SalesmanName will not have any spaces.

```
char arr[1000]; 
cin`>>arr;
```

If you enter "XYZ ABC" as name, then arr[] will store only "XYZ" while "ABC" will remain in the input stream.

For this question you can create a Salesman Class which will encapsulate all the functions nd data required for each Salesman . As the company has only 6 workers you can make a array of 6 object of Salesman Class. So that you can refer to particular salesman's commission as SalesMan[i].getCommission(). Moreover class will help to expand to more number of workers later.